# Why is there a slight black border around my shared legend in ggarrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=as.factor(cyl))) +
geom_point(size=2, shape=23)

panel <- ggarrange(p, p, nrow=1, common.legend = TRUE, legend="right") +  bgcolor("white")
```

[image]

Do you see the black block in the upper right, I have seen this issue more than once when trying to do a shared legend, adding `bgcolor("white")` helps a bit but not completely. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with `common.legend = TRUE` and was seeing black blocks in the plots. Setting the background to white with `ggsave` resolved it for me:

```
ggsave("out.png",width=6, height=10, units="in", dpi=300, bg="white")
```